# How to resolve "Refused to display 'file' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive" with AJAX files?

Tags: ajax, drupal

I am implementing a module on a local Drupal 7 site. When I try to use any of the modules AJAX functions, I get the message:

> [Report Only] Refused to display
>   'http://localdev.mysite.com/system/ajax' in a frame because an
>   ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Reading about this, this seems be an error associated with displaying iframes from other servers. Yet this is an AJAX file on the same server.

Would anyone know how I could resolve this?

Comment: It can be a bug in some of 3rd party modules. Try turning them off. Also try drupal's default theme. Default Drupal installation won't do that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a false alarm. After further research I see this is meant to be here - it's just a 'Report' intentionally put in place by the server admins, not an error.